# java/android how to use contains() on a string of a url

Tags: java, android, url, jsoup, contains

This i think should be fairly straightforward but i'm kind of a novice programmer and for whatever reason this is not working properly

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO**

I'm trying to scrape a website using jsoup i want to get all URLs between x and y but not if there images,

**WHAT I'M DOING**

I'm getting all the URLs between x and y but some of them are images I'm achieving this using the .contains() method checking if it starts "https" and this works to get all the links i want but a lot of them are image links ending with png jpg or gif but when i added the nested if block to check if its a png or jpg etc and not add it to the list if they are, they're still being added to my list,

```
            Elements metaElems = doc.select("meta");

            for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
                     String content = metaElem.attr("content");
                        if (content.contains("https")){

                            if (content.contains("png")){
                                buffer.append("PNG");
                            }
                            if (content.contains("gif")){
                                buffer.append("GIF");
                            }
                            if (content.contains("jpg")){
                                buffer.append("JPG");
                            }
                            else {
                                linklist.add(content + "\r\n");
                            }
                        }
                }
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I'm aware that all urls can be gotten from the href tag but this results in far too many irrelevant links i've also tried getting a substring of the last three characters and checking them like

```
                    String sub = content.substring(content.length() - 3);
                    //and checking it in my if statement like
                    sub.equals("png")
```

I've tried using jsoup to check if it has an img tag but this hasnt worked and ive also tried checking the header of the link to set a boolean value and check this before trying to add the link to the list like this

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://foo.bar/w23afv")
.openConnection();
String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
boolean image = contentType.startsWith("image/");
```

but this gives me a SSL handshake error which I read up on and tried to solve but the easiest way I found would be to have no trust manager and i don't like that idea, 
I've searched alot on this and i think it might be a case of the string having different characters and apparently i can get around it with Regex but as stated i'm kind of a beginner and i'm struggling to understand or solve this any help?

Comment: For image extensions, you may want to use `endsWith(String)` instead of `contains(String)` .

Comment: thank you i had tried this but as i was making the fundamental error in my if else statement it probably wasnt working for that reason so ill use this now thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
if (content.contains("png")){
    buffer.append("PNG");
}
if (content.contains("gif")){
    buffer.append("GIF");
}
if (content.contains("jpg")){
    buffer.append("JPG");
}
else {
    linklist.add(content + "\r\n");
}
```

Now imagine that `content` contains `png`. First `if` condition is satisfied, ok. Point is it goes further. The content doesn't contain `jpg` so the `else` block is invoked and the `content` is added to your LinkedList.

What you need to do is change second and third `if` to `else if`. Also consider using `startsWith()` and `endsWith()`.